# Soap webservice returning different responses from same call

Tags: web-services, delphi, iis, soap

I have a `SOAP` service developed in `DELPHI` and published on `IIS`. Testing the services we found some strange behaviour, the soap response structure changes after we call an operation with a wrong parameter type.

The test case is simple, we are calling this simple operation:

```
Test1_1(i:Integer; var s:string);
```

**Call 1 (right parameter type)**

*Request:*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:WS_MCH_PrivadosIntf-IWS_MCH_Privados">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Test1_1 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <numero xsi:type="xsd:int">1</numero>
      </urn:Test1_1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

*Response:*

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <Test1_1Response xmlns="urn:WS_MCH_PrivadosIntf-IWS_MCH_Privados">
         <res xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">TEST1_1 OK</res>
      </Test1_1Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Call 2 (wrong parameter type)**

*Request:*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:WS_MCH_PrivadosIntf-IWS_MCH_Privados">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Test1_1 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <numero xsi:type="xsd:int">a</numero>
      </urn:Test1_1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

*Response:*

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>'a' is not a valid integer value</faultstring>
         <faultactor/>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Call 3 (right parameter type, and response changes here from the first call)**

*Request:*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:WS_MCH_PrivadosIntf-IWS_MCH_Privados">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Test1_1 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <numero xsi:type="xsd:int">1</numero>
      </urn:Test1_1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

*Response:*

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:WS_MCH_PrivadosIntf-IWS_MCH_Privados">
      <NS1:Test1_1Response>
         <res xsi:type="xsd:string">TEST1_1 OK</res>
      </NS1:Test1_1Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the first call and the third are exactly the same, but the response is different. Like i said before, it changes after an invokation with the wrong parameter type. 
The client of the service doesn't recognize the response after it changes.

Any clues about this behaviour?
I need the server to answer always in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Idera and send them your test case.

I had a similar problem a few months ago, as what you described, and I couldn't resolve this error. I contacted Idera (the owner of Delphi) and reported this as a VCL error.

I did get a reply and fix, but I am unable to share the hot-fix with you.
(Please do not contact me for this...)

This is a hot-fix for Delphi Seattle or Update 1 fix for Delphi Berlin.

Comment: Why do you think is a vcl bug?, The server has no visual components.

Comment: The error is inside the source-code of IdHttp, Soap.WebNode, Soap.(something) System.Classes, System.Rtti. For that, you need to contact Idera for the hotfix if you are using lower version of Delphi.